# Access VBA: SQL String with string tablefield converted as date

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access, vba

Normally I figure out my `DateTime` issues in `VBA` and `SQL` by trial and error, but in this case I have hit a wall.

I am not even sure I can do what I want.

I have a temporary table with fields F1, F2, etc.

Field F7 contains a date as a string n the format dd/MM/yyyy.

Now, I want to copy the data from the temporary table, to a table where the data in field F7 should be stored in a `Date/Time` field. The format of this field is Short Date (dd-MM-yyyy).

I have tried using `CDate()`, `Format()` and `Trim()` alone and in several combinations, along with padding my date data with ## and adding brackets [] to my table `fieldname`, but I simply cannot find the correct combination.

This is my code. The `importedDate` works fine because I am using a variable. But for the field F7, I am mixing the `SQL` query with the `VBA` date conversion, and it is not working for me:

```
Sub MoveImportedData()
Dim SQLStr As String


SQLStr = "INSERT INTO TblDebitorSaldoListe " _
& "(CompanyCode,CompanyName, CustomerNumber, CustomerName, OneTimeCustomerName, TermsOfPayment, NetDueDate, Reference, " _
& "DunningBlock,Comment, ReminderOne, ReminderTwo, DebtCollection, TotalAmountDKK, TotalNotYetDueDKK, TotalOverdueDKK, " _
& "ReminderOneFile, ReminderTwoFile, NoReminder, ImportedDate) " _
& "SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, #" & CDate("F7") & "#, F8, F9, '', '', '', '', F10, F11, F12, '', '', 0, '" & CDate(Date) & "' " _
& "FROM TEMP WHERE Len(F1)=4" _

MsgBox SQLStr

DoCmd.RunSQL SQLStr

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am using Access 2013.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add in the code you've tried using to convert the `DataType`? It could be that there was something wrong with the code you were using here?

Comment: I have tried this combination among others: & "SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, 'CDate(Format(Trim(F7), " & Chr(34) & "dd-mm-yyyy" & Chr(34) & "))', F8, F9, '', '', '', '', F10, F11, F12, '', '', 0, '" & CDate(Date) & "' " _

Comment: Can you declare a variable, (`newDate`, for example) as type of `DateTime`. Run a `SELECT` query to get the value of F7, then run a VBA Convert command on the value, then insert it this way? It may require a loop to do it for each row, so not the most efficient way, but just to check it works.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the reply. I will try it.

Comment: This combination gives me a wrong, but usable SQL Query output: & "SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, " & Format(CDate(F7), "dd-mm-yyyy") & ", F8, F9, '', '', '', '', F10, F11, F12, '', '', 0, '" & CDate(Date) & "' " _. It returns 30-12-1899 as date for field F7.

Comment: Hi again. I think my issue is that my dates are on the form '23.10.2016' which we use in Denmark. Using Replace(date, ".", "-") seems to do the trick for me and allows me to go on.

Comment: You can also set the format that you want to use in the code (eg dd/MM/yyyy, etc). Glad your issue is solved. Add an answer explaining how you solved it, as this will also help other users in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really quite simple:

```
& "SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, DateValue(F7), F8, F9, '', '', '', '', F10, F11, F12, '', '', 0, Date() " _
```

or, if F7 is dotted (corrected to have single-quotes with Replace):

```
& "SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, DateValue(Replace(F7, '.', '-')), F8, F9, '', '', '', '', F10, F11, F12, '', '', 0, Date() " _
```

Comment: Sorry, got the quotes for _Replace_ mixes up. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Gustav's suggestion.

DateValue did not work, perhaps because of my danish locale. I think it returned a wrong date format (for me), which resulted in `NULL` being inserted into the `F7` field of the table. That is this did not work, but might work for others with different date formats:

```
& "SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, DateValue(Replace(F7, ""."", ""-"")), F8, F9, '', '', '', '', F10, F11, F12, '', '', 0, Date() " _
```

But `CDate` solved my issue along with adding extra `"`. This worked for me:

```
& "SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, CDate(Replace(F7, ""."", ""-"")), F8, F9, '', '', '', '', F10, F11, F12, '', '', 0, Date() " _
```

Thank you both very much for quick and useful help!

Comment: _DateValue_ will convert strings like '23-10-2016'. Also, except for pure integers, there should not be an expression that _DateValue_ can't convert which _CDate_ can. So what does your data really look like, please?

Comment: It contains data on the form: 25.02.2017
08.10.2016
01.12.2016
02.01.2017
21.10.2016

Comment: DateValue will convert these after replacing the dots, so something else must be going on.